Side of the video got cropped after stabilization. How to tell Davinci Resolve not to do that?
I'm stabilizing a vertical video. Somehow, the side of the video always got cropped. I don't think it should be since the new video is 1080p. If you see the screenshot below, I marked the cropped area yellow. How to tell DaVinci Resolve not to do that? Thanks.


